# Difference between Long [ ] array and long [ ] array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, math

Is there any difference between long array (`long[] arr`)  and Long array (`Long[] arr`)?

Is the sorting complexity the same?

Answer (score 2):

Sorting `long[]` and `Long[]` using `Arrays.sort` will involve different sorting algorithms: long[] is sorted with a "dual-pivot quick sort" while Long[] is sorted with "tim sort" (a version of merge sort). They will have the same `O(n log n)` asymptotic time complexity, but the *constant multiplier* may be different. Operations on primitives and arrays of primitives like `long[]` are typically more efficient than operations on wrapper objects.

Answer (score 1):

`Long[]` is an array of objects, whereas `long[]` is an array of primitives. Sorting complexity is the same for both, but by wrapping primitive into an object, you're introducing additional memory overhead.